# Optimal overlapping windows of audio time series using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, signal-processing

I would like to perform various analysis on audio time series such as RMS of overlapping windows to obtain an envelope running on GPU.

The code below demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish but is quite inefficient for long time series. It is essentially what the `torch.stft` is probably doing prior to applying FFT but I don't see an equivalent public method.

```py
import torch


win_len = 1024
hop_len = win_len // 4
B, C, N = 4, 2, 44_100
M = (N - win_len) // hop_len + 1
x = torch.rand((B, C, N))
y = torch.zeros((B, C, M, win_len))
for m, n in enumerate(range(0, M * hop_len, hop_len)):
    y[:, :, m, :] = x[:, :, n : n + win_len]
```

Comment: By inefficient, you mean in terms of time it takes to run ?

Comment: I achieve 11s with `y = torch.stack([x[:, :, n : n + win_len] for n in range(0, M * hop_len, hop_len)])` vs 18s for the code you posted (repeated 25 times) but I don't see how to improve it further with pure python for now

Answer (score 0):

The fastest equivalent solution I could find is the following:

```
win_len = 1024
win_hop = win_len // 4    
B, C, N = 4, 2, 44_100 * 10  # [batch, channels, samples]
x = torch.stack([torch.stack([torch.arange(0, N) for _ in range(C)]) for _ in range(B)]).to('cuda')

def stack_windows(x):
    N = x.shape[-1]
    M = (N - win_len) // win_hop + 1
    y = torch.stack(
        [x[:, :, m : m + win_len] for m in range(0, M * win_hop, win_hop)],
        dim=-2,
    )
    return y


%%timeit
windows_stack(x, win_len=win_len, hop_len=hop_len)
torch.cuda.synchronize(x.device)
```

When running on CUDA, this shows a 18x improvement on my system.